# Spark Cast StructType / JSON to String

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a new-line delimited json file that looks like

```
{"id":1,"nested_col": {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": ["arr1", "arr2"]}}
{"id":2,"nested_col": {"key1": "val1_2", "key2": "val2_2", "key3": ["arr1_2", "arr2"]}}
```

Once I read the file using `df = spark.read.json(path_to_file)`, I end up with a dataframe whose schema looks like:

```
DataFrame[id: bigint,nested_col:struct<key1:string,key2:string,key3:array<string>>]
```

What I want to do is cast `nested_col` to see it a string without setting `primitivesAsString` to true (since I actually have 100+ columns and need the types of all my other columns to be inferred). I also don't know what `nested_col` looks like before hand. In other words, I'd like my `DataFrame` to look like

```
DataFrame[id: bigint,nested_col:string]
```

I tried to do

```
df.select(df['nested_col'].cast('string')).take(1)`
```

but it doesn't return the correct string representation of the JSON:

```py
[Row(nested_col=u'[0,2000000004,2800000004,3000000014,316c6176,326c6176,c00000002,3172726100000010,32727261]')]`
```

whereas I was hoping for:

```py
[Row(nested_col=u'{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": ["arr1", "arr2"]}')]
```

Does anyone know how I can get the desired result (aka cast a nested JSON field / `StructType` to a String)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest parsing JSON and inferring schema just to push everything back to JSON sounds a bit strange but here you are:

- Required imports:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import types
  from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, concat_ws, concat, struct
  ```
- A helper function:

  ```py
  def jsonify(df):
      def convert(f):
          if isinstance(f.dataType, types.StructType):
              return to_json(f.name).alias(f.name)
          if isinstance(f.dataType, types.ArrayType):
              return get_json_object(
                  to_json(struct(f.name)), 
                  "$.{0}".format(f.name)
              ).alias(f.name)
          return f.name

      return df.select([convert(f) for f in df.schema.fields])
  ```
- Example usage:

  ```py
  df = sc.parallelize([("a", 1, (2, 3), ["1", "2", "3"])]).toDF()

  jsonify(df).show()
  ```

  ```
  +---+---+---------------+-------------+
  | _1| _2|             _3|           _4|
  +---+---+---------------+-------------+
  |  a|  1|{"_1":2,"_2":3}|["1","2","3"]|
  +---+---+---------------+-------------+
  ```

Comment: Aah, to_json was added in 2.1 whereas I was using spark 2.0.1. This works perfectly for me!